# styling and scaling svg map

Tags: reactjs, svg

```js
//function returns a new svg from using path d attribute passed to the function

svgMap = (mapData) => {
    const source = `
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 8 6" height="150" width="150" transform="scale(2)">
  <path fill="#bad9e3" d='${mapData.path}'/>
  </svg>`;
    const optimizedSVGDataURI = svgToMiniDataURI(source);
    return <Image src={optimizedSVGDataURI} />;
    
    }
    
   
 //inside react component render method
 render() return ( 
 <Table.Row>
    <Table.Cell className="map-inline">
    {this.svgMap(mapData)}
    </Table.Cell> 
 </Table.Row>)
```

I have data containing svg paths. How can I dynamically center the paths within the svg viewbox.

[image: 1]

I want to position the svg map at the center of the row. The issue is related to the way am assgning the viewBox values. Currently am forcing values and I need a dynamic way of generating viewbox to have the svg map centred.

Comment: You can get the size and the position of your path using the [getBBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method. please edit your question and add the svg code

Comment: @enxaneta I have managed to add a code snippet of what I did maybe it can give you some insight if you need more clarity regarding my problem